# How to get the JSESSIONID from Contexts.getSession() during preDestroyContext.SESSION?

Tags: jsf, seam

Working with JBoss AS 5.1, JSF 1.2 and Seam 2.2, I'm trying to log session openings and closings.

AFAIK, at the moment of the `org.jboss.seam.preDestroyContext.SESSION` event, in case of a session timeout, there's no `FacesContext` which seems natural as there is no running HTTP request, so I can't get the session ID from it. But there's still a Seam session context which is available by `Contexts.getSession()`.

When I dynamically inspect the `Contexts.getSession()` object in a debugger, I can see the `JSESSIONID` in some inner `Map`. I would like to do something like:

```
String sessionId = Contexts.getSession().get("JSESSIONID");
```

But apparently, `JSESSIONID` is not the right key to retrieve the session ID. I tried `id`, `SessionId` without success. The `SessionContext.getNames()` method returns a list of keys:

- `anonPersistentPermissionResolver`
- `loggedUserId`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.ruleBasedPermissionResolver`
- `org.jboss.seam.web.session`
- `com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.SerialId`
- `org.jboss.seam.international.timeZoneSelector`
- `org.jboss.seam.international.localeSelector`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.defaultResolverChain`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.persistentPermissionResolver`
- `javax.faces.request.charset`
- `crumbs`
- `org.jboss.seam.core.conversationEntries`
- `debateId`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.credentials`
- `com.sun.faces.logicalViewMap`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.identity`
- `org.jboss.seam.security.rememberMe`

The value for `org.jboss.seam.web.session` doesn't contain the session ID.

How do I get the session ID from `Contexts.getSession()`?

Comment: You said that you saw it in the debugger. The associated key should also be visible in there.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the question and for your comment. Actually the inspection of the `Contexts.getSessionContext()` variable shows an inner _map_ field of type `ServletSessionMap` which in turn contains a _session_ field (type `StandardSessionFacade`) which in turn contains a _session_ field (type `StandardSession`). And that last _session_ field contains an _id_ field (type `String`) which is the value I'm looking for... I'm still kind of lost...

Comment: @BalusC _The associated key should also be visible in there._ While inspecting a bit further, it appears that the _session_ field (of type `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`) contains a map field named _attributes_. Looking at the seam and apache code, it appears that this _attributes_ map is the actual map on which the `org.jboss.seam.contexts.SessionContext.get(String)` method is based. And the session id doesn't seem to appear in that map. The _id_ field is "brother" field of _attributes_ in `StandardSession`. But I still don't know how to get its value programmatically...

Comment: I solved my problem by putting explicitly the session ID at session creation time (which is an Http request so session ID is available) in the SESSION context. This is my ugly yet simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a classic HttpSessionListener to log what you need. Put in your web.xml:

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.yourcompany.YourSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
...
```

The listener implementation is like this:

```
package com.yourcompany;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class YourSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {   

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourSessionListener.class);

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        log.info("creating http session: " + event.getSession().getId());                       
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        log.info("destroying http session: " + event.getSession().getId());        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it should actually meet my need. I'm just a little bit disappointed not getting it to work with the already available seam listener. Having the variable containing the session ID at runtime and not knowing the code to read it is quite frustrating !

Comment: I tried your solution, but it looks like there's a incompatibility between the HttpSessionListener and the SeamListener

Comment: This solution should have nothing to do with seam. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: Well, at server start, the listeners registering fails with a `NoClassDefFound` exception on my version of `com.yourcompany.YourSessionListener`. I suppose - but I'm not sure - this is an incompatibility with seam. Moreover, I need the listener method to be a seam component to inject some conversation scoped components (`entityManager`) which is likely to be impossible within a standard listener (not a seam listener)

Comment: @koyaga It has nothing to do with Seam. You didn't deploy the class correctly. You should adjust the package and classmate to suit your own packages.